# Slab UnReclaimable Using 14GB

Tags: linux, cache, selinux

I need help to understand what is this slab unreclaimable memory usage, I know that is related to cache.

Here is the output of /proc/meminfo

```
cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:       23373884 kB
MemFree:         1547460 kB
MemAvailable:    1976756 kB
Buffers:           65252 kB
Cached:           683132 kB
SwapCached:       550824 kB
Active:          5387748 kB
Inactive:        1211904 kB
Active(anon):    5046500 kB
Inactive(anon):   883848 kB
Active(file):     341248 kB
Inactive(file):   328056 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:      49807356 kB
SwapFree:       48152620 kB
Dirty:               300 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       5782956 kB
Mapped:            83180 kB
Shmem:             79064 kB
Slab:           14816228 kB
SReclaimable:     122592 kB
SUnreclaim:     14693636 kB
KernelStack:       10112 kB
PageTables:        23640 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    61494296 kB
Committed_AS:    7223420 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:   3080192 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:     4161408 kB
DirectMap2M:    19955712 kB
DirectMap1G:     2097152 kB
```

Output of slabtop

```
 Active / Total Objects (% used)    : 462600052 / 462704921 (100.0%)
 Active / Total Slabs (% used)      : 3642734 / 3642734 (100.0%)
 Active / Total Caches (% used)     : 100 / 129 (77.5%)
 Active / Total Size (% used)       : 14790386.41K / 14811378.02K (99.9%)
 Minimum / Average / Maximum Object : 0.01K / 0.03K / 8.00K

  OBJS ACTIVE  USE OBJ SIZE  SLABS OBJ/SLAB CACHE SIZE NAME
461003776 461003776 100%    0.03K 3601592      128  14406368K avc_xperms_data
212224 209627  98%    0.06K   3316       64     13264K anon_vma_chain
150528 138072  91%    0.01K    294      512      1176K kmalloc-8
136758 134952  98%    0.09K   2973       46     11892K anon_vma
131808 131700  99%    0.50K   4119       32     65904K kmalloc-512
123765 121256  97%    0.21K   3345       37     26760K vm_area_struct
100716  86900  86%    0.19K   4796       21     19184K dentry
 91136  83900  92%    0.02K    356      256      1424K kmalloc-16
 88064  85602  97%    0.03K    688      128      2752K kmalloc-32
 56520  56520 100%    0.13K   1884       30      7536K kernfs_node_cache
 56384  32811  58%    0.12K   1762       32      7048K pid
 53760  46542  86%    0.06K    840       64      3360K kmalloc-64
 40992  34741  84%    0.57K   1464       28     23424K radix_tree_node
 37464  26514  70%    0.09K    892       42      3568K kmalloc-96
 36834  36368  98%    0.19K   1754       21      7016K cred_jar
 36540  35688  97%    0.66K   1524       24     24384K proc_inode_cache
 23062  22296  96%    0.59K    887       26     14192K inode_cache
 23010  20591  89%    0.10K    590       39      2360K buffer_head
 21828  21828 100%    0.04K    214      102       856K Acpi-Namespace
 21213  18227  85%    1.06K    717       30     22944K ext4_inode_cache
 18208  17665  97%    0.12K    569       32      2276K kmalloc-128
 17646  17646 100%    0.08K    346       51      1384K task_delay_info
 15936  15838  99%    0.25K    498       32      3984K skbuff_head_cache
 15744  15332  97%    1.00K    492       32     15744K kmalloc-1024
 13566  13306  98%    0.04K    133      102       532K ext4_extent_status
 13179  13136  99%    0.69K    573       23      9168K sock_inode_cache
 12580  12580 100%    0.05K    148       85       592K ftrace_event_field
 10860  10860 100%    1.06K    362       30     11584K signal_cache
 10731   9611  89%    0.05K    147       73       588K Acpi-Parse
 10290  10116  98%    0.19K    490       21      1960K kmalloc-192
  8608   8505  98%    2.00K    538       16     17216K kmalloc-2048
  7095   7095 100%    0.24K    215       33      1720K tw_sock_TCPv6
  6944   6944 100%    0.07K    124       56       496K Acpi-Operand
  6854   6854 100%    0.69K    298       23      4768K files_cache
  6576   4818  73%    0.25K    212       32      1696K pool_workqueue
  6080   6080 100%    0.06K     95       64       380K ext4_io_end
  5882   5882 100%    0.12K    173       34       692K jbd2_journal_head
  5625   5408  96%    2.06K    375       15     12000K sighand_cache
  5612   5512  98%    0.70K    244       23      3904K shmem_inode_cache
  4590   4590 100%    2.12K    306       15      9792K mm_struct
  4227   3915  92%    1.06K    158       30      5056K nfs_inode_cache
  4032   4032 100%    0.06K     63       64       252K dmaengine-unmap-2
  3685   3377  91%    5.94K    737        5     23584K task_struct
  3431   3431 100%    0.05K     47       73       188K mbcache
  3072   3072 100%    0.02K     12      256        48K selinux_file_security
  2496   2496 100%    0.12K     78       32       312K scsi_sense_cache
  2331   2331 100%    0.19K    111       21       444K dmaengine-unmap-16
  2040   2040 100%    0.02K     12      170        48K fsnotify_mark_connector
  1920   1302  67%    0.12K     60       32       240K dtrace_task_cache
```

The slabtop shows that the avc_xperms_data is using 14gb of memory, searching on the internet I found that this is related to selinux, but it is not enabled/active on this server.
Any help?

As Requested:
sestatus

```
sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled
```

avcstat

```
timeout 10 avcstat 1
ERROR: open: '(null)/avc/cache_stats': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please post the output of the command `sestatus`.

Comment: Also provide the output of `timeout 10 avcstat 1`

Comment: @MichaelHampton
Both info was provided, any help ?

Comment: @MatthewIfe added the output

Comment: Well, that's odd. Maybe it's an old obscure kernel bug. Is your system up to date? When is the last time you rebooted?

Comment: @MichaelHampton the server is up fo 237 days now.
it is a Oracle Linux Server release 7.7

Comment: 237 days? Holy carp, nothing should be up that long. Get it up to date and rebooted as soon as you can.